# Bpython-like editor/IDE?

Tags: python, eclipse, vim, bpython

I love bpython's fast, comprehensive autocompletion and I'd really like to use it right inside my editor/IDE. Is there a way to integrate it into vim/gedit/eclipse/etc?

Thanks.

Comment: It only works because it has runtime information, namely it has all the definitions in scope and can therefore simply search the names in scope, the members of objects, etc. - it's impossible to have those informations statically in an editor. There may be something different to the same effect (but then there are several duplicates) and I may have misunderstood it.

Comment: I didn't know about bpython. It looks good, thanks for the info. From what I see, most of its autocompletion features are already available in vim through its omni-completion system: method/variable names, path completion. I don't know if there's a plugin giving you code hints, though. The method/variable completion and code hinting is already available in Eclipse, Komodo and probably every Python-aware IDE. I've never seen path completion in any of those, though. What does bpython's manual says about integration? Can it work in "headless mode" and be used by other tools? The way it returns it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar question. I wanted to have bpython in Vim as i was getting tired of switching between terminal and Vim. Turns out there is a fantastic plugin ( as there usually are for Vim :) called **conque** . [Docs are here](http://code.google.com/p/conque/wiki/Usage)

After u install it at the Vim prompt do **:ConqueTerm bpython** and smile :) I think it works for Ipython and others as well..